# jquery sortable item options for dragging inside and outside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i have 2 lists, all items of them can be moved to the other list and inside its list, except the item with classname called "header" , but i want "header" can be moved inside its parent only. can someone help me? thank you so much. here is my code:

```
$("div.main-task-content").sortable({
    scroll: true,
    revert: true,
    helper: clHelper,
    delay: 200,
    connectWith: $('.main-task-content'),
    handle: '.drag-handler',
    update : function (event,ui) 
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?